# Can't upload pictures into my directory. Why isn't my code working?

Tags: php, image, upload

Here is my code. I understand that the picture goes first into the wamp/tmp directory and as you can see my code should move it into my database, but it doesn't. The file simply stays in the tmp directory of WAMP and won't move to the database. I checked the the upload direction in the php.ini file and it's empty, as it should be (upload_tmp_dir = ""). I just want to upload pictures into my database and display them later in a user profile, but I can't move forward until this problem isn't solved.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="probe";
?>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=
"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

// check if a file was submitted
if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
{
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
}
else
{
    try {
    $msg= upload();  //this will upload your image
    echo $msg;  //Message showing success or failure.
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Sorry, could not upload file';
    }
}

// the upload function

function upload() {
    include "file_constants.php";
    $maxsize = 5000000; //set to approx 10 MB

    //check associated error code
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        //check whether file is uploaded with HTTP POST
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {    

            //checks size of uploaded image on server side
            if( $_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize) {  

               //checks whether uploaded file is of image type
              //if(strpos(mime_content_type($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {
                 $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                if(strpos(finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {    

                    // prepare the image for insertion
                    $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

                    // put the image in the db...
                    // database connection
                    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());

                    // select the db
                    mysql_select_db ($db) OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

                    // our sql query
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_image
                    (image, name)
                    VALUES
                    ('{$imgData}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}');";

                    // insert the image
                    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
                    $msg='<p>Image successfully saved in database with id ='. mysql_insert_id().' </p>';
                }
                else
                    $msg="<p>Uploaded file is not an image.</p>";
            }
             else {
                // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
                $msg='<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
                <div>Maximum File limit is '.$maxsize.' bytes</div>
                <div>File '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].' is '.$_FILES['userfile']['size'].
                ' bytes</div><hr />';
                }
        }
        else
            $msg="File not uploaded successfully.";

    }
    else {
        $msg= file_upload_error_message($_FILES['userfile']['error']);
    }
    return $msg;
}

// Function to return error message based on error code

function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
    switch ($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The first thing you should _always_ do when you have an issue with a php script running inside an http server: look into the http servers error log file. There is little sense in _guessing_ what the issue might be if you can simply read what the issue _is_ in that log file.

Comment: Thank you, but I never used the log file before. Any idea how to begin with? (I'm an amateur programmer).

Comment: You have to learn that, you cannot program php without. Look into the configuration of your http server. In the there location of the log files is configured. In case of an apache http server you are looking for the command `ErrorLog .....`. That should be where your error log file is. Take care to pick the right one, there may be different log files defined for different virtual hosts inside your http server. You are interested in the _last_ entries in that error log file.

Comment: All about errors: http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1301076